# Remove HTML tags and its contents from a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following string:
`const test = "This is outside the HTML tag. <title>How to remove an HTML element using JavaScript ?</title>";`

I'd like to remove the content within all HTML tags in that string. I have tried doing `test.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')`, but this only removes the HTML tags rather than all the content within it as well. I would expect the outcome to only be 'This is outside the HTML tag.'.

Is it possible to remove HTML tags **and** its contents within a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini nope, that does the same thing as the regex in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to remove the HTML element via Regex, it's much more straightforward to create and populate a **DOM Fragment** using:

```
let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML = test;
```

and then remove the `<title>` element from that, using:

```
myDivTitle = myDiv.querySelector('title');
myDiv.removeChild(myDivTitle);
```

---

**Working Example (One Element):**

```js
const test = "This is outside the HTML tag. <title>How to remove an HTML element using JavaScript ?</title>";

let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML = test;
myDivTitle = myDiv.querySelector('title');
myDiv.removeChild(myDivTitle);
const testAfter = myDiv.innerHTML;
console.log(testAfter);
```

---

The above works for *one* element (`<title>`) but you stated:

> I'd like to remove the content within all HTML tags in that string

so let's try something more ambitious, using:

```
myDiv.querySelectorAll('*')
```

---

**Working Example (All Elements):**

```js
const test = "<title>How to remove an HTML element using JavaScript ?</title> This is outside the HTML tag. <h1>Here we go...</h1> So is this. <p>This is going to save a lot of time trying to come up with regex patterns</p> This too.";

let myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML = test;
myDivElements = myDiv.querySelectorAll('*');

for (let myDivElement of myDivElements) {
  myDiv.removeChild(myDivElement);
}

const testAfter = myDiv.innerHTML;
console.log(testAfter);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed a very elegant solution.

Comment: @Adam - Happy to have saved you from [_Tony the Pony_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/#answer-1732454)

Comment: Variable declaration missing from the following line:
`for (myDivElement of myDivElements) {` -> `for (let myDivElement of myDivElements) {`

Comment: Nicely caught, @christopher.theagen - thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace everything between the two elements by putting a Wildcard character between two of your regex

```js
const test = "This is outside the HTML tag. <title>How to remove an HTML element using JavaScript ?</title>";

console.log(test.replace(/(<([^>]+)>).*(<([^>]+)>)/, ''))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works in this particular example (which is what I had asked for). I have merely accepted the other response because it caters for a more complex example.

Comment: Here's a simpler regex: `test.replace(/<.+?>.*<\/.+>/, '').trim()`

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this :

```
var html = "<p>Hello, <b>Frields</b>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
alert(div.innerText); // Hello, Frields
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my question was to remove all the contents within the HTML tags (which I believe this does not do, unless I am mistaken).